# Why are we here if the chances are zero

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, olam-haba-world-to-come

A somewhat philosophical question (based on a saying by Albert Einstein):

If God existed eternally and Olam Haba is infinite in time and this world is finite in time duration, then the chances of one existing in this world right now is zero.

Hence our existence here is but a finite dot relative to the infinities in both direction.

Yet we are all here in this world. Any explanation?

Edit: it is true that if one picks a random point in a number line, each point has zero probability but since there are infinite points, the chance of picking a point is really 100%. however here the case is akin to a number line where all points are blue except for one single red point (say the number Pi) and one randomly chooses this unique red one out of all the other infinite blue points. the probability here is truly zero.

Comment: I think you're better off moving this to the philosophy.SE

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39403/discussion-on-question-by-ray-why-are-we-here-if-the-chances-are-zero).

Comment: The only reason one point on this timeline is red, is because it is you. Saying, why am I viewing the world from this vantage point in time is another way of asking, why was I born at this stage of the world's history? And since you would be asking that regardless of when you were born, it's also another way of asking, why was I born at all? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about philosophy and not about Judaism.

Comment: Why are we all here? Because G-d put us here, and He doesn’t care about statistics. *Why* did He put us here? Now *that’s* a good question, and one that’s on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

I think I understand your question. I’ll try to answer it the best I can.

You question is based on the assumption that God's existence is compared to an infinite time line. He was here for an infinite amount of time and He will forever remain here, but at any instance He experiences only the ‘now’. Yet, if we describe God's existence as an infinite time line, we run into problems. If we point to a specific point on this infinite time line, we can evaluate two things: one, a list of historical events which have occurred up until this point. And two, that God has existed up until this point in time, albeit an infinite amount of time. We do not know, however, if He will continue to exist. That is one problem with your theory; as Jews, we DO know and believe He will forever exist.

Another problem is the following: Free will aside, we know that God knows what we will do before we do it. If I decide to pick up a pen, God knew that (forgive the past tense), before I even picked it up. If your theory is correct, that God's existence is compared to an infinite time line, then at the point in time that I picked up the pen, God was with me in the room— at the same point in time that I was. Not only does this idea make God seem more vulnerable and human-like, but when He is at the point on this line that I picked up the pen, He is not at any other point on the line. How is He to know whether or not I will pick up the pen if He is only at the current point in time? We have already said that God DOES know that I will pick up the pen, but with your theory how is He to know?!

Because of the problems listed, I appears to me, that God existence can not be compared to an infinite time line. I believe God is living above time all together. He is so infinite, His existence doesn't have the word time in it at all. Time is ABSOLUTELY NOTHING to Him. Therefore He can not live on an infinite TIME line. He is living in an area or "universe," if you will, that is not affected by time. He has no beginning or end, rather he just... is. Imagine the history time line in your head. You see the beginning of the Earth on the left, and Masiach at the end, on your right. Where is God on this time line? He isn't. Rather he is living above it, not bound by time at all but rather is just existing. He understands the rules of time— he has created it— but does not live by them. He knows what you will do because he is at every point in time, all at the same time. He was, He is and He will be, not at separate points in time, but at the same time! He doesn't exist like we do. When people die, they don't wait until they are resurrected, rather they are like God, I think, in the sense that they are living in an "alternative universe" where they just... are.

To answer your question, it isn't that history is an infinite line, where we could be placed anywhere. It is merely a finite line, and God lives separately. Therefore the line of history isn't infinitely long, but rather only 5000 years long. The chances, therefore, that we were born when we were are infinitely less then what you suggested.

(Considering your theory was correct...) God isn't bound by percentage. You can not say that because there is a 0% chance of being placed where we were we can not be placed there. God is infinite and can do infinite things. So even if there was a 0% chance, that doesn't affect God. Imagine God deciding to place me in year 2016 and then an idea called 0% saying, "Um, no, You can't do that."

Answer (score 1):

Time is an accident (or measurement) of motion and causality. Time is the passing of potentiality to actuality. Olam haba has no further cause as it is the final cause of our existence.

> The final goal is the attaining to the world to come, and it is to it that the effort must be directed.
>
> Rambam, Introduction to Pereq Heleq

There are no further causes or motions in olam haba.

> In the world to come there will be no eating and no drinking, no washing and no anointing and no marriage; but only the righteous sitting with crowns on their heads enjoying the splendour of the Shechinah.
>
> Berakhoth 17a

As there is no further causes or motions in olam haba, it cannot be said that there is time. Olam haba is eternal and infinite in the same way Hashem is, via the negative. Hashem is eternal because he is not subject to change or time, and the same is said for olam haba. Your question assumes a cardinally infinite passage of time in which this world is the preamble for. This is a categorical error; that is, applying a property to something to which the property cannot apply. Like asking the weight of blue.

Answer (score 1):

[Genesis 1:26-28](http://sefaria.org/Genesis.1.26-28):

> וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֔ים נַֽעֲשֶׂ֥ה אָדָ֛ם בְּצַלְמֵ֖נוּ כִּדְמוּתֵ֑נוּ וְיִרְדּוּ֩ בִדְגַ֨ת הַיָּ֜ם וּבְע֣וֹף הַשָּׁמַ֗יִם וּבַבְּהֵמָה֙ וּבְכָל־הָאָ֔רֶץ וּבְכָל־הָרֶ֖מֶשׂ הָֽרֹמֵ֥שׂ עַל־הָאָֽרֶץ׃
>
> וַיִּבְרָ֨א אֱלֹהִ֤ים ׀ אֶת־הָֽאָדָם֙ בְּצַלְמ֔וֹ בְּצֶ֥לֶם אֱלֹהִ֖ים בָּרָ֣א אֹת֑וֹ זָכָ֥ר וּנְקֵבָ֖ה בָּרָ֥א אֹתָֽם׃
>
> וַיְבָ֣רֶךְ אֹתָם֮ אֱלֹהִים֒ וַיֹּ֨אמֶר לָהֶ֜ם אֱלֹהִ֗ים פְּר֥וּ וּרְב֛וּ וּמִלְא֥וּ אֶת־הָאָ֖רֶץ וְכִבְשֻׁ֑הָ וּרְד֞וּ בִּדְגַ֤ת הַיָּם֙ וּבְע֣וֹף הַשָּׁמַ֔יִם וּבְכָל־חַיָּ֖ה הָֽרֹמֶ֥שֶׂת עַל־הָאָֽרֶץ׃
>
> And God said: ‘Let us make man in our image, after our likeness; and let them have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creepeth upon the earth.’
>
> And God created man in His own image, in the image of God created He him; male and female created He them.
>
> And God blessed them; and God said unto them: ‘Be fruitful, and multiply, and replenish the earth, and subdue it; and have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over every living thing that creepeth upon the earth.’

The Creator of all made us and put us here. Therefore, the probability that we are here is 100%.

Comment: yes but why now. He had an eternity to do this, and there is an eternity of time after now.

Comment: @ray I don't understand the question. The Torah says that God created everything. It doesn't say anything about a pre-existing eternity within which He identified a point in which to create everything. We exist now, and there is a now, because He said we should exist now.

Comment: Excellent answer to a meaningless philosophical question.

Comment: if you dont like the question then close it instead of giving a ridiculous answer like this

Comment: @ray, closure is for questions that don't fit here, for one of various reasons. I have not voted to close the question, because in invoking God, it's about Judaism. On the same token, I am surprised at your rejection of an answer that cites God's word on the subject. If you want the question to be answered oustide the context of Torah, I agree with Matt that you should ask on the Philosophy site (presumably leaving God out of it).

Comment: the question is not where in the torah does it say we exist. if i were to give an answer like this, i would get barraged with down votes

Comment: @ray the question asks for an explanation of the fact that we are here in this world, despite the fact that a proposed line of philosophical reasoning suggests that we oughtn't. The Torah provides the explanation: because God said so. Your proposed philosophical reasoning seems, in suggesting an a priori probability of our existence, to be unaware if the fact that we live, in fact, a postiori to a pretty important event that the probability of our existence is dependent on. That event is described in Genesis 1.

Answer (score 0):

Olam habo had a beginning, it is spiritual and exists parallel to this world (there are stories of people who visit it)

There is no chance for us to exist, it is just that G-d Almighty created us,

Comment: Had a beginning so if is not infinite in time

Comment: Olam Haba might of had a beginning in the sense that it was created with the world, but I find it hard to believe that people in Olam Haba actually have to sit around and wait for Masiach. Also, how would it be fair if I died a year before Masiach? If Olam Haba is bound by time, then I would only have a year in Olam Haba, while people on the same level as me, 1000 years ago, experienced pleasure for 1000 extra years. Obviously God could deal with these problems accordingly, but none of us really know the answers to these questions. I find it hard to believe that people wait to be resurrected.

Comment: Also, people who visit Olam Haba could be tapping into a universe where time doesn't exist, like Eliyahu HaNavi

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the disappearance of the black bird in the closing scene of the Hitch-hicker's guide to the galaxy, which vanished beyond all possibility, your question assumes we are inherently matter, which would be sad if it was true.

If on the other hand the universe is a state of mind of God, then understanding his whim in creating us as we are is infinitely improbable and therefore fits the maths you have described.

Answer (score -1):

G-d has no limitations, therefore one cannot even say that G-d is not limited, for that very statement would be setting a limit for the infinite G-d.

The world that we live in and the time that we live in is G-d's will and this world and this time is chosen by Him, at the same time that he is truly infinite.

In the Midrash it says that "G-d wanted to have a dwelling below"

This is why we are here: to make ourselves and the world around us into a dwelling for G-d.

Comment: "G-d has no limitations" and "G-d is not limited" are the same thing. How can you say one but not the other? This post is nonsense.